# Lucene Index optimization

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Is there a progmmatic way in Lucene to know if the index is optimized or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[IndexReader.isOptimized](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#isOptimized())

Comment: `isOptimized()` has been deprecated since Lucene 3.